# How to run my friend's React Project on my computer after i downloaded it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[here](https://github.com/KimDuer/sis) i have a project of one of my friend but i really don't only know that how to run this project in my machine, i have installed it in my laptop and request `npm install` but i do not able to find out how to run the project!

**node  ^10.16.0**

**react ^16.8.6**

and i have run

**npm install**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the commands in `package.json` under the section 'scripts' and prefix it with `npm run ...`.

in your case use: `npm run dev-server`